# UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle: loaded the "View" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I have created an .xib file then deleted it by sending it to trash. After that time I have started to take an exception as stated in the title. My project do not use interface builder file(neither storyboard nor xib/nib) at all. I have looked up whole project files but could not see any connection with xib file.

How to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any xib file in your project? Creating window programmatically?

Comment: @Anil i am sure.I fixed the problem.
The steps; First clean the project, close Xcode, reset simulator, open project from the file(not the shortcut on organiser) then run it.

Comment: @erdemgc deleting the app on the simulator should be sufficient ;)

Answer (score 2):

First you should clean your project and delete the app from simulator, and it will be ok. (Even if you deleted the `xib` to trash, it still exists in the bundle.)